# Symfony query notLike Alpha

Tags: regex, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to only return records that start don't start with alpha eg [a-z] and only return numeric and symbols.

The query

```
...
$query->andWhere(
         $query->expr()->notLike('l.name', ':letter')
         $query->setParameter('letter', '[a-z]' . '%');
);
...
```

The above still returns everything. If I replace `[a-z]` to `a` then it will return everything except for anything that starts with `a` so I know the query works.

I added https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Regexp.php to my application

config.yml

```
doctrine:
         orm:
             dql:
                string_functions:
                                REGEXP: Bundle\DataBundle\Doctrine\Extension\Regexp
```

Query

```
$query->setParameter('letter', 'REGEXP([a-z])' . '%');
```

But still no luck, it still returns everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`REGEXP`** in Doctrine:

```
public function getNotLike(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p.wantedWord');
    $qb->where(......)
    ->andWhere('REGEXP(p.wantedWord, :word) = false')->setParameter('word', '[a-z]');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```